# 2-step contact form, URL field on the site, others inside popup

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

[image]

The only thing I'm stuck at is how to have the text entered for the URL field on the site go to the popup URL field, where's the full form once fake "submit" button is clicked [its purpose is to trigger the popup window].

To clarify, I've done everything else just the URL field can't figure it out.

This [website](https://sumome.com/) has it going the way I want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JS script that will double the value of your fake URL field and real URL field of the form in the pop-up.
Sure you may use jQuery for it as well.

Try this answer by Richard Dalton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896287/jquery-passing-value-from-one-input-to-another

Comment: @JohnCy: Glad to help you! Take care!